# Sending Webform submissions

Tags: 8, webforms, crm

We installed Webforms and Salesforce suites and we'd like to create new leads in Salesforce based on the webform submissions.

I created a webform with 3 fields.

```
email:
  '#type': email
  '#title': Email
company:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': company
last_name:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'last name'
```

Then I created a mapping with Salesforce linked to webform submissions. In the mapped fields, I think I have to use tokens. So I have the following

```
[webform_submission:original:values:email] --> linked to Salesforce email field
[webform_submission:original:values:company] --> linked to Salesforce Company field
[webform_submission:original:values:last_name]--> linked to Salesforce Last Name field
```

When I test my form, I get an error message that says "Drupal push failed".

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: You left an important part, D7 or D8?

Comment: @NoSssweat 

Indeed, sorry.... We're using D8.

Comment: Are there any other related errors in `/admin/reports/dblog` ?

Comment: yes, there's 1 error

Comment: yes, there's 1 error (too long to display in 1 answer)

Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'salesforce_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {salesforce_mapped_object} (revision_id, drupal_entity__target_id, drupal_entity__target_type, salesforce_mapping, salesforce_id, created, changed, entity_updated, last_sync_status, last_sync_action, force_pull) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,

Comment: :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 29 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => webform_submission [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => webform_leads [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1548768674 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1548768674 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => push_create [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => )

Comment: in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->handleQueryException() (line 683 of /srv/www/stg.graduateinstitute.ch/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php).

Comment: When you say "We installed Salesforce suites" are you referring to **[this](https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce)** ?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, this module was installed along with Webform.

Comment: The error you're getting is due to SalesForce returning an empty `salesforce_id` value. I've never used SalesForce, but you could try using **[one of the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCN2m.png)** webform **[addons](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-add-ons)** which were created specifically to integrate SalesForce with the webform module.